# Como usar a funcao LAG: retornar valor baseado no valor da linha anterior SQ;

Tags: sql, funções, query, windows

Ola,

tenho um problema em SQL e estou com dificuldade de resolve-lo: gostaria de pegar primeiro valor que foi calculado baseado em outros parametros da tabela, e em seguinte aplicar uma nova formula pegando o valor resultado deta primeira linha:

```
A           B       X   Y           Z   P
3305623815  0.04    1   5/1/2023    0   0.96
3305623815  0.04    1   5/2/2023    0   0.92
3305623815  0.04    1   5/3/2023    0   0.88
3305623815  0.04    1   5/4/2023    0   0.84
3305623815  0.04    1   5/5/2023    0   0.8
3305623815  0.04    1   5/6/2023    0   0.76
3305623815  0.04    1   5/7/2023    0   0.72
3305623815  0.04    1   5/8/2023    2   2.68
```

O meu objetivo e criar essa coluna P, para ter o valor 0.96(primeira linha), o calculo e: (X-B+Z),
e o valor da seguinte linha se da (valor da linha P1 anterior - B + Z), e da terceira linha(P2 - B + Z), e assim por seguinte. Eu tentei utilizar a funcao LAG, mas esta sempre retornando o valor da primeira linha que e 0.96. Alguma ideia qual query utilizar para retornar os valores da coluna P ?

Answer (score 0):

A função LAG pode ser usada para retornar o valor de uma coluna em uma linha anterior em um conjunto de resultados ordenados. Você pode usá-la da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT A, B, X, Y, Z,
   (X - B + Z) AS P,
   LAG(P, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Y) AS P1,
   LAG(P, 2) OVER (ORDER BY Y) AS P2
FROM your_table
```

Isso retornará uma nova coluna chamada P, que contém o valor calculado como (X - B + Z) para cada linha. As colunas P1 e P2 conterão os valores das colunas P nas linhas anteriores, ordenados pelo valor da coluna Y.

Por exemplo, a primeira linha da tabela resultante terá o seguinte valor nas colunas P, P1 e P2:

```
P: 0.96
P1: NULL
P2: NULL
```

A segunda linha terá os seguintes valores nas colunas P, P1 e P2:

```
P: 0.92
P1: 0.96
P2: NULL
```

E assim por diante.

Comment: Ola https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/147812/douve, nao funcionou. Esta query retorna diferentes colunas, e o valor continua o mesmo, 0.96, em P,P1,P2... E tambem eu nao quero colunas diferentes, mas na mesma coluna P, ter linhas diferentes na mesma coluna P

Comment: Publique um exemplo num SqlFiddle